# How to locally read and write a C file

Tags: compilation, c, output, input

How can I read and write a C file locally?

I want to be able to input from a file and output to a file locally in ArchLinux. I'm using GNU Emacs text editor to write my code and I'm submitting my codes to online competitive programming websites like codeforces.com, etc. Those are the sites for algorithm problem solving. They provide you some algorithmic, mathematical problems and you submit your code. Those sites have "online judges" where they automatically provide input to your code and checks the output. According to that output "online judges" give verdict of your code.

Thus, I want to only locally read from an input file and write to an output file. I have checked "[`fopen`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/fopen.3.en)" from Arch Linux [manuals](https://man.archlinux.org/man/fopen.3p.en) but I didn't understand how to execute their codes. I used to have `freopen` in my windows codes a decade ago and used to work properly. A lot of competitive programmers (or algorithm problem solvers) use the code below to input and output locally in their laptops, PCs, and most of them have Windows OS.   Most probably the code below works for them too because I keep seeing it in their codes they submit to online judges.

```
#ifdef LOCAL
        freopen("a.in", "r", stdin);
        freopen("a.out", "w", stdout);
#endif
```

I wrote a simple code that inputs two numbers, adds them, and outputs the sum: https://ideone.com/fk224Q.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(void) {
    #ifdef LOCAL
        freopen("a.in", "r", stdin);
        freopen("a.out", "w", stdout);
    #endif
    int a, b, c;
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    c=a+b;
    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

You can manipulate the `stdin` there online on the IDE (ideone.com here) directly there and it will give you the desired output, `stdout`, there on online ide directly. Same applies for "online judges" of competitive programming websites like [codeforces.com](https://codeforces.com/), [codechef.com](https://www.codechef.com/), [UVa online judge](https://onlinejudge.org/), [Sphere OJ](https://www.spoj.com/), etc.

I don't know if `fopen()`, `fclose()` codes would be a problem for online judges since they provide input automatically and checks your output. But in my `freopen()` code above and in these `fopen()`, `fclose()` codes you give the `pathname` and file afaik; and it should be done only locally not online. For instance, I want to be able to read from not "`a.in`" but from "`input`", and write not to "`a.out`" but to "`output`". Yes, I know I just need to edit the filename in my code and I did it now, locally on my Arch but it didn't work. My code outputs some gibberish. I have compiled it via terminal: `gcc addition.c -Wall -o output` to no avail. I know there might be syntax errors in my code but what I'm looking for is how to handle this local input-output problem. Your help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I input "`2 3`" and got "`5`" on online ide, it gave me the output I wanted. [image: I input "2 3" and got "5" on online ide].

My OS is Arch Linux with GUI, text editor is GNU Emacs, compiler is GCC.

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: Why do you need to open the file in your code instead of using shell redirection? `./my-executable < input-file > some-output-file`

Comment: `freopen("a.in", "r", stdin)` is basically the same as running the program with the redirection `< a.in` and should do the same as closing `stdin` and then `stdin = fopen(...)`. I'm not exactly sure what it is you're asking, since it sounds like you asking about how `fopen()` and friends work, and that's probably better answered by any C tutorial, the reference manuals, and some working it out. And if you're asking about opening files locally, I'm not exactly sure if the part about online environments is relevant for that.

Comment: For online environments, you'll need to figure out how the input is given and work based on that. For your local environment, you get to decide, but following the customs of the online environment (and then just taking that into account when launching the program) would at least mean you can use identical code in both cases. Anyway, if you only say "My code outputs some gibberish" without showing the exact code you run, the exact way you run it, and the exact inputs you give it, no-one can help you.

Comment: @muru, thanks. I googled "shell redirection". I don't know how to use your code. In the current folder there 3 files: "code.c", "input" and "output". So if I understood it correctly I should write "./code.c < input > output", is that correct? Or do I need to do it while compiling or after compiling?

Comment: @ilkkachu, I showed the things that you asked for: my code is shown above, the way I compiled it is shown above, input (2 and 3 here) is shown on the ideone link I have provided above, the output (5 here) is also there on ideone link. My code works on ideone but it doesn't work the way I want on my Arch Linux. Yes, I am asking about "fopen()" and similar "read and write" commands in C. I checked 2 or 3 reference manuals but I didn't understand how to write them and execute them. I guess these things require some advanced C knowledge, which I lack.

Comment: @garakchy you use it with the compiled executable, but ... you do know how to compile to get an executable file, right? With what you have shown in the question (`gcc addition.c -Wall -o output`), it looks like you think `gcc addition.c` is to run the code.

Comment: @garakchy, excuse me? You wrote in the post that "[you] have compiled it via terminal: gcc addition.c -Wall -o output to no avail." and I don't see that compilation done on the linked page, nor any of the output, nor how you run the resulting binary, if you get one, that is. Those are things you could have included in the post, so they'd be available without someone going explicitly looking.

Comment: @muru, yes, I thought "gcc filename" is both a way to compile and run the file :) It looks like I have a long way to go. I will continue to look at the references and mess around with the C codes. I know I will get used to it by time and maybe start fixing my own C-related problems in future. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ilkkachu, oh sorry, you are right; I could've done better. ideone.com, an online IDE,  compiles and runs codes for you. I learnt my first C coding in that website, not locally on my devices. Thus I don't know well how to compile, run, catch errors locally yet. I'm learning it. I must admit that online ide made me a bit lazy with the comfort it provided: no dealing with execution, just code and provide input and get the desired output :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, finally I was able to get `input` and `output` in C, but I don't know if it is `LOCAL` or not.

I changed my code's `read` and `write` file to `.txt` extension and it worked.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
 // #ifdef LOCAL
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
 // #endif
    int a, b, c;
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    c=a+b;
    printf("%d", c);
    printf("\nHello World");
    return 0;
}
```

This is my `input.txt` content: `5 6`

And this is my `output.txt` content:

```
11
Hello World
```

Thanks to [@muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru), I learned `gcc filename` was just a way to compile my code, not run it. After compiling though, I ran my code by `./a.out`. Is that a universal way to run your code?

I know, you can specify the output when compiling the C code via `gcc filename -o outputfile` but I didn't specify here during compiling. Let's say I compiled and output my C into a text file, `.txt` extension here, can I compile `./output.txt`? I tried it but it gave error of `bash ... permission denied`.

If I `freopen() read` from `a.in` and `freopen() write` to `a.out`, then I couldn't manage to do it. I tried it. Maybe `freopen()` works only in text files with `.txt` extension. Then I would need to run via `./a.out` always.

Anyway, I fixed my own problem, even though partially.

Thanks everyone. Your educative comments would be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't specify an output filename to `gcc` when compiling, it uses `a.out` as the default. "Let's say I compiled and output my C into a text file, .txt extension here" the extension is irrelevant here (and to your fix as well, you just needed to use the complete filename of the actual input and output files) and the statement really doesn't make sense otherwise too - if you compile your C code, the GCC output isn't going to be *more* C code.